# Ajax form submit I want to change the value of a form element by id for the next call by the script from return value in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to have the response from php update the html form element by id. I'm using Ajax to submit the form, and upon success it needs to change the value of the html element by ID. How can I make this work? Because right now it does nothing!

```
$.ajax({
    url:"autosave.php?save=true",
    method:"POST",
    data:{"subject":subject,"body":body},
    dataType:"text",
    success:function(data)
         {
         // $('#id').value = this.responseText;
         document.getElementsByName('id')[0].value = this.responseText;
         $('#autoSave').text("Updated");
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"autosave.php?save=true",
    method:"POST",
    data:{"subject":subject,"body":body},
    dataType:"text",
    success:function(data)
         {
         // $('#id').value = this.responseText;         
         jQuery('#id').val( data );
         $('#autoSave').text("Updated");
         }
    });
```

(Not tested)

Comment: Thank you, the use of .val( data ) solved the problem. There was also an error on my side. The correct way to set a variable with ajax is: val()

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

```
 $.ajax({
         url:"autosave.php?save=true",
         method:"POST",
         data:{"subject":subject,"body":body},
         dataType:"text",
         success:function(response)
                 {
                  $('#id').val(response);
                  console.log(response);   
                  $('#autoSave').text("Updated");
                  }
});
```